# QGraphicsItem::paint(): how to check if QGraphicsScene is printed

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I have a class RadBox subclassed from QGraphicsItem. I want the items to have different background and foreground colors depending on whether its scene is displayed, printed or copied to clipboard. Here is the item's `paint()` method:

```
void RadBox::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
           QWidget *widget)
{
    if(isSelected()) painter->setPen(grayPen);
    else painter->setPen(blackPen);
    if(standing!=0) painter->setBrush(redBrush);
    else painter->setBrush(grayBrush);
    painter->drawRoundedRect(-35, -30, 70, 60, 3, 3);
    painter->setFont(fnt);
    painter->drawText(QRectF(-35,-10,70,20),Qt::AlignCenter,QString::number(box_number));
    painter->setFont(fnt2);
    painter->drawText(QRectF(-35,5,70,20),Qt::AlignCenter,QString::number(power));
}
```

Copying to clipboard:

```
void Scheme::on_copyButton_clicked()
{
    QPixmap pm(scene.itemsBoundingRect().width()*3,scene.itemsBoundingRect().height()*3);
    QPainter pnt;
    pnt.begin(&pm);
    scene.render(&pnt);
    pnt.end();
    QApplication::clipboard()->setPixmap(pm,QClipboard::Clipboard);
}
```

Printing:

```
void Scheme::print_preview(QPrinter* printer)
{
    QPainter pnt;
    pnt.begin(printer);
    scene.render(&pnt);
    pnt.end();
}
```

How to let items know if a scene is painted, printed or copied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to myself: `painter->device()` has a member `devType()`.

```
switch(painter->device()->devType())
{
case QInternal::Widget:
    if(isSelected()) painter->setPen(grayPen);
    else painter->setPen(blackPen);
    if(standing!=0) painter->setBrush(redBrush);
    else painter->setBrush(grayBrush);
    break;
case QInternal::Pixmap:
case QInternal::Printer:
    painter->setPen(blackPen);
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::white));
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```